# change menu behavior with purely CSS or JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, css

Need to change a menu with pure CSS or JAVASCRIPT 
The menu is for an online store. There are categories and the subcategories are collapsed within the categories. I want to have the sub-cats be auto expanded when the page loads so that a user doesnt have to click these to expand. My Domain is: wwww.tackpal.com

[image: current state]

[image: new state desrired]

Comment: Try inspecting the category items and see if they have a special class like `open` or `active`, if so then set those classes on the items you want open in the html markup. If not then you could trigger a click event via javascript on page load

Comment: there is an active class

Comment: media="screen"
a:active {
  color: #123851;
}

Comment: Can you please post the code you've tried so far? Your question reads as if you haven't tried it yourself, and you just want us to write the code for you, which isn't what we're really here to do. We're here to help you solve problems you've at least attempted to solve yourself.

Comment: Please provide a small example of code to reproduce your problem. Working with a "live" site is not feasible because as you try to fix the problem you are presenting a moving target. Further more  this question becomes meaningless to future users as they have no reference point for the question. Also, having to dig through your entire page code is tedious and time consuming, help us help you. Finally and most importantly, by breaking it down to just the problem, you may come across a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I took a look at your web site and when a user clicks a category, they are actually taken to the web page of that specific category. **Thus, currently the sub categories are NOT included in the home page.**

Your first solution is to edit the menu template in your CMS if they allow it.

**A SOLUTION / HACK BELOW, but changing the template in your CMS would be better**

If you add this code, when a user visits the home page, the script below will tell the browser to make Ajax calls to all the categories that have sub-categories. When each category page source is returned, it finds the sub-category list and inserts them into the home page's menu respectively.

*To test this code out. You can simply go to the home page of your web site. Then, open the console and paste in the first functions and then the script inside the onload function.*

```
//a simple function used to make an ajax call and run a callback with the target page source as an argument when successful
function getSubPageSource(url, successCallback)
{
    var xhr = XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
        {
            //when source returned, run callback with the response text
            successCallback(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.send();
}

//wrap in onload event
window.onload = function() {  

    //find all categories with sub categories
    var categories = document.getElementsByClassName('has-subcategories');
    //loop through each category
    for (var ii = 0, nn = categories.length; ii < nn; ii++)
    {
        //use a closure to pass in a static ii
        (function(ii)
        {
            //get element
            var element = categories.item(ii);
            //find id
            var id = element.getAttribute('data-category');
            //find url
            var href = element.getAttribute('href');
            if (id && href)
            {
                //found
                getSubPageSource(href, function(data)
                {
                    //find sub categories
                    //trim off everything before where id shows up first
                    var substrSource = data.substr(data.indexOf('data-category="'+id+'"'));
                    //trim off the remaining of the category title
                    substrSource = substrSource.substr(substrSource.indexOf('</a>'));
                    //trim off where the next category is found
                    substrSource = substrSource.substr(0, substrSource.indexOf('home-categories-main'));
                    //trim off where the next category starts, leaving source of all sub categories
                    substrSource = substrSource.substring(0, substrSource.lastIndexOf('<a '))

                    //insert to main menu after the title
                    console.log(id, substrSource);

                    //create new node capable of having children
                    var newNode = document.createElement("span");
                    //insert new source into the new node
                    newNode.innerHTML = substrSource;

                    //insert new node after element
                    element.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, element.nextSibling);
                });
            }
        })(ii);
    }
};
```

This script may only work in the **HOME PAGE ONLY** as I have not tested it out on your other pages. If added to other pages, it might create duplicate sub-category lists on respective category pages.

*NOTE: A huge downside to this second approach is that everytime someone visits your homepage, their browser in the background is in turn visiting all the category pages that have sub-categories. This means that your server will have to serve several pages for each home page visit.*

**I really recommend finding a way to edit the menu template in your CMS instead of the script above**

Pasting script above, your homepage generated the necessary links as seen in this screenshot below.
[image: Screenshot of home page after running script above in console.]

Answer (score 1):

first you need to find how its collapsed/expanded.
in most cases menu would be collapsed with a class, and expanded with another class added by javascript. (or even swapped)

without looking at the css its hard to say anything really.
either edit the current default class of the categories

```
height:0;
```

or

```
display:none;
```

remove that. also dont forget to remove click function bound to the menus, so that it doesnt fire if someone clicks on the menu

again, without code its hard to say

edit: nevermind, i followed your link. the subcategories are inserted via ajax call i think. i checked few js files and theyre all minified, if you dont have source, you can just forget about doing this